# Is my rating good?

Tags: rating

I used to play chess a lot when I was younger (started when I was 2), but then a few years ago I stopped at around 10. I recently picked it up again and wanted to see how good I still am, so I took an online test. It says I'm rated 1746. I turn 16 in about a month. Is my rating good for my age?

Comment: depends on who you ask

Answer (score 6):

When people ask if they are "good", the question becomes, good compared to what?

Assuming your USCF rating would really be 1746 (which is hard to say from an online test), that would not put you in the top 100 US players age 15.  You would need a rating of 1931 to make that list, currently.  But it would get you the 26th spot on the top US girls age 15 list.  It would put you in the top 4% of junior players, about the top 35% of adults, and about top 10% overall.  It beats my current rating by two points.  If you had played in my high school league, you probably would have won almost every game.

Of course, the best way to find out how good you are isn't to take a test - it's to play games!  It's one thing to be able to spot a mate in 3 when you're told there's something special about the position; it's quite another to see it when you're playing a game or to cause such a position to happen in the game in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

That depends on the test you took, and on the person you ask. A Grand Master will teill you that 1746 is bad, a beginner will tell you that it is good. Best way to evaluate your chess skills is to play games and tournaments against humans.